# R ggplot2: show only shape in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm plotting some data collected in plots in different compartments. Therefore each datapoint has a colour (plot) and a shape (compartment). In the legend I'd like to show the symbols for the compartments in black, but I do not want to show the colour legend.

[image: Example plot]

As I only added `scale_shape_manual(values = c(3:8))` and no `scale_colour_manual`, I'd hoped it wouldn't appear but it does.

I tried some stuff with `guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = ...))`, but can't find a way to remove it.

Example code:

```
library(ggplot2)

pred_X <- c(10, 20, 25, 8, 12, 20, 18, 30, 40)
obs_X <- c(9, 18, 27, 10, 15, 19, 16, 32, 40)
afdeling <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=3)
plot <- rep(c("plot 1", "plot 2", "plot 3"), times=3)
output <- data.frame(pred_X, obs_X, afdeling, plot)

ggplot(aes(x = pred_X, y = obs_X), data=output) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=afdeling, colour=plot)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1:3)) +
  #guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = NULL)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,60)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,60)) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', colour="black", se=F, lwd=0.7)
```

Comment: Just add `+  guides(color = "none")` to the plot.

Comment: Perfect! Guess I was making that line of code too complicated... If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H 1 had the solution:
"Just add + guides(color = "none") to the plot."

Solved the problem easy and perfectly.